# Can I Create USDT Wallet With Python

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, wallet

I want to create USDT wallet with python. Than I want to check wallet periodically and send usdt another wallets. I google it but I can't find anything. Any library or Api? I will use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

There is a rather easy way to create a usdt walled in python.
You need to install [pywallet](https://pypi.org/project/pywallet/). Then using that library you can create a USDT wallet doing the following:

```
# create_usdt_wallet.py

from pywallet import wallet

# generate 12 word mnemonic seed
seed = wallet.generate_mnemonic

# create usdt wallet
w = wallet.create_wallet(network="USDT", seed=seed, children=1)

print(w)
```

For more info check out the [documentation](https://openbase.com/python/pywallet/documentation)